# Finding the conditions based on the idea from optimization for the a.s. equality of two RVs

Tags: probability-theory, optimization

I am working on the problem of finding the conditions, based on the idea from optimization, under which two RVs are equal a.s. (almost surely).

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two RVs $\in \mathbf{R}$. Assume that $X\stackrel{d}{=}Y$ (equal in distribution).

I know if $Y=aX + b$, i.e., $Corr(X, Y)=1$, $X$ and $Y$ are equal a.s., i.e., $a=1$ and $b=0$. Please help me get started by this: is it possible to associate probability with optimization in this way: If an optimization problem, e.g., $\min_{X} \|1 - Corr(X, Y)^2\|_2$, is solved, $X$ and $Y$ are equal a.s.

Assume the above association is valid. When it turns to multivariate RVs, i.e., $X$ and $Y \in \mathbf{R^n}$, I know $Y=AX$ ($A$ is invertible) results in the a.s. equality of $X$ and $Y$. However, it seems difficult to reuse the above optimization problem since cross-correlation of $X$ and $Y$ is intricate (Assume $\min_X \|Y-AX\|_2$ is not expected to use).

Could someone please tell me whether it is legitimate to frame an optimization problem as the condition for the a.s. equality of RVs? If that is the case, please share some ideas on finding such a condition for multivariate RVs.